# WorldEdit - replace block if condition is true

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-worldedit

I have a significant amount of chunks of farmland on some hills that I want to plant crops on all at once. I'm considering using WorldEdit to do this but I don't want to just select the whole general area of the farmland and replace all air with seeds (this actually works, from prior experience on a more powerful server) because it'll probably crash my server.

Is there a way to use conditional statements to the effect of "if air block is directly above farmland replace with seeds" to plant these seeds?

Comment: If you have figured it out, please post it as an answer so others after you can benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and easiest way to do this is just to do `//overlay seeds`.

This places seeds above all of the blocks exposed to the sky in the selection.